How do I append to slice in struct of multidimensional in Go?
New to Go...
I have the following:
type class struct{
  Name    string
  Age     int
  Address string
  Phone.  int
}

SchoolClassList := [12][4]class{}

NewStudent := class{}

To start, I initialize for 12 because I will have 12 different grade levels for each class.  And each class will start with 4 students.  I want to be able to append to any of the class as more students arrive.
I tried doing the following to append to grade 2
SchoolClassList[2] = append(SchoolClassList[2],NewStudent

However I am getting the following error:
First argument to append must be a slice; have SchoolClassList[2] (variable of type [4]class


[N]X defines an array of size N of type X. An array is a fixed-sized object, you cannot append to it. []X defines a slice with size  0 of type X. You can append to it. Read about arrays and slices.

You might want to work through the Tour of Go once more to recap the language fundamentals.

Append works on slices (you are using array).
use this
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    type class struct {
        Name    string
        Age     int
        Address string
        Phone   int
    }

    SchoolClassList := [12][]class{}

    fmt.Println("Before: ", SchoolClassList)

    NewStudent := class{}

    SchoolClassList[2] = append(SchoolClassList[2], NewStudent)

    fmt.Println("After", SchoolClassList)
}


Thanks for the array vs slice.  I got it to work
